# Problem on applying xsl to xsd in opera

Tags: xslt, xsd, opera

Well I was told to apply xsl on xsd. Ok. But opera doesn't allow that.

Xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="sammple.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="global" type="globaltype"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name='global']">
       <xsl:text>sample</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i call sample.xsd on firefox, there is no problem. It produce the text "sample".

But if I call it from opera, there comes the error which is:

> `This document had an invalid XSLT
>   stylesheet. Error message from the
>   XSLT engine: Error: invalid XML
>   output: unexpected text
>   (non-whitespace text outside root
>   element)`

What can I do?

**Edit**: My environment:

Opera : Version 11.01
Firefox: Version 3.6.13
Http server : lighttpd 1.4.28

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your output only includes one piece of text (`sample`), and the stylesheet doesn't specify that text should be output, Opera's probably expecting the output to be XML and getting upset when it's not a valid XML document.

Try either adding `<xsl:output method="text" />` to the stylesheet, or enclosing `<xsl:text>sample</xsl:text>` in an element, for example `<root><xsl:text>sample</xsl:text></root>` (Note that the `<xsl:text>` element is actually superfluous in this instance, `<root>Sample</root>` would do.)

Comment: Adding <xsl:output method="text" /> solved my problem. Thank you. I did not even think of that

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Presto (Opera) and Webkit (Chrome, Safari) reparse `xml` serialization method's output.